# ColorFunction in ListContourPlot3D raising error when using more than one argument

Tags: plotting, color, visualization

The documentation of `ColorFunction` states that in `ListContourPlot3D` your chosen function gets the arguments `x`, `y`, `z` and `f`. However, if you actually use any argument other than the first an error is raised in Mathematica 12.2, yet strangely enough the plot is (most of the times) shown as expected.

Consider for example

```
list1 = Table[{x, y, z, x^2 + y^2 - z^2}, {x, -1, 1, .05}, {y, -1, 1, .05}, {z, -1, 1, .05}]~Flatten~2;

ListContourPlot3D[list1, Contours -> {0.3}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, Hue[z]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

This produces the error

```
Function::fpct: Too many parameters in {x,y,z,f} to be filled from Function[{x,y,z,f},Hue[z]][0.3].
```

But the generated graphics seem OK:
[image: ColorFunction in ListContourPlot3D]

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Must be a bug since `ContourPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 - z^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Contours -> {0.3}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, Hue[z]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False]` is well.

Comment: I can't reproduce that error in MMA 12.2.0 (Linux, on the cloud). What version and OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mathematica 12.2.0.0 on a Windows 10 desktop PC